# Why don't work about using delegate to set property value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I try to use delegate to reset my ViewControllerA (HomePage) property "type" value when I logout.
But I set breakpoint and my delegate function work success.
When I login again, and print my property "type" in ViewWillAppear. It's also cache old value before I logout.
Please tell me what's wrong with me.
Thanks.

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, CustomDelegate {

    enum Type: Int {
    case book = 0 
    case pen      
    }

    var tmpType: Type?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        printBBLog("tmpType: \(tmpType)") //before I logout the value is "pen",and I login again the value is "pen". 
    }

    func clearType() {
        printBBLog("clear")
        self.tmpType = nil
        printBBLog("\(self.tmpType)") 
    }

    @objc func bookBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.tmpType = .book
    }

    @objc func penBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.tmpType = .pen
    }
}


class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    var delegate: CustomDelegate?

    func doLogout() {
        let vc = ViewControllerA()
        self.delegate = vc
        self.delegate?.clearType()
    }

}
```

Comment: You are constructing a new `ViewControllerA()` out of nowhere and setting your delegate to this meaningless instance. If you use storyboard and segue, you should obtain the `UIViewController` instance in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
      sender: Any?)`. If you use `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, the `UIViewController` instance is its return value.

Comment: But viewcontrollerA and viewcontrollerB are inside in tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Then you should have references to both instances in the tabbarcontroller, set the delegate there.

Comment: You can use `tabBarController.viewControllers` to access the view controllers in it [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621185-viewcontrollers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621185-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of your `ViewControllerA`. since you are using the `UITabBarController` you can access you `ViewControllerA` from your `ViewControllerB` and assign the delegate. after that you will get your desired result. for reference please check below code.

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    var delegate: CustomDelegate?

    func doLogout() {
        let viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
        if let vc1 = viewControllers[0] as? ViewControllerA {
        self.delegate = vc1
        self.delegate?.clearType()
      }
    }

}
```

if you are using UINavigationController inside the UITabBarcontroller then use:

```
if let vc1 = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0] as? ViewControllerA)
```